# Make a script executable only in specific directories bash

Tags: bash, alias

I have the following structure of my programme

```
cd programme1
ls
> input/ output/ scripts/
```

In the scripts folder there is a bash script called: submit

submit accepts an input file as the first argument and produces the output file specified as the second argument.

I constructed it so that this script can be called from any place. For instance, I can call it in the following way from the current folder: programme1

```
scripts/submit test_in test_out
```

However I find this slightly unfriendly for users. I.e. I would like the script to be callable in the folowing way:

```
submit test_in test_out
```

for as long as the user is in any subdirectory of the main folder programme1. If the user calls submit from outside of programme1, nothing should happen:

```
cd ..
submit test_in test_out
> submit: Command not found.
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: The user needs to include the scripts directory in their `PATH`, or they need to copy or symlink it to somewhere already within `PATH`.

Comment: @jordanm has the correct answer.  If this is for multiple users, I would go with the symlink idea.  Otherwise, everyone needs to add that directory to their path.